# How to change the Help Description in Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I´ve created some Models in QGIS 2.18 and the help in the Model shows only what is in the description field. Thats the way I want it.

But I migrated to QGIS 3.4, and now when I type something in the Modeler help, all descriptions like input, output and so on, are displayed.

Is there a way to limit the information displayed, to be like in 2.18?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The descriptions are saved within the model file itself. So you can edit these to show specific or no descriptions at all. Find your model file (you can click the *Options* button in the Processing Toolbox to see the location of your stored models) and open it in your favourate text editor. Look for the lines like the following:

```
<Option name="help" type="Map">
    <Option name="ALG_CREATOR" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="ALG_DESC" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="ALG_HELP_CREATOR" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="ALG_VERSION" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="HELP_URL" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="SHORT_DESCRIPTION" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="layer" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="native:mergevectorlayers_1:res" type="QString" value=""/>
</Option>
```

You can then add/modify the `value` parameter or remove the line entirely so that it is not shown in the help page of your model.

Comment: this section of the .model3, just affect the part that I write in the help tab. Don´t clear the other tags it shows, like Inputs and Outputs.
I'm looking into all the lines trying to find something that works.